# SOXXY: a daemon stated IRC client project

Tags: python, python-3.x, socket, chat

This script is basically a proxy service; except it doesn't require an active client connection. In fact it expects the client connection to connect before, and disconnect after every transaction. Once running the proxy will buffer all incoming bytes, and will dump those bytes to the client upon request. Before I go any further and begin working on the IRC client intended to be used with this, I am posting here to persuade any feedback regarding the project in its current state from readers here:

**soxxy.py**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from socket import socket
from threading import Thread as thread
from sys import getdefaultencoding as enc
from sys import byteorder
from sys import argv

enc = enc()
CNCT, SEND, RECV, DISC, STAT = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4

class sox:
        def recv_t(self, s):
                while self.run:
                        try: self.buff += s.recv(8192)
                        except: continue
        def process(self, lo):
                try: bs = lo[0].recv(8192)
                except: return
                op, data = bs[0], bs[1:]
                if op is CNCT:
                        data = str(data, enc)
                        host, port = data.split(":")
                        self.sock = socket()
                        self.sock.connect((host, int(port)))
                        self.run = True
                        thread(target=self.recv_t, args=(self.sock, )).start()
                elif op is SEND: self.sock.send(data)
                elif op is RECV: lo[0].send(self.buff); self.buff = bytes()
                elif op is DISC: self.run = False; self.sock.close()
                elif op is STAT: bytes("error: %s" % (str(self.serr), ), enc)
        def server(self, port, host):
                ss = socket()
                ss.bind((host, int(port)))
                while True:
                        ss.listen(1)
                        self.process(ss.accept())
        def __init__(self, argv):
                self.sock = None
                self.buff = bytes()
                self.serr = False
                self.server(argv[1], argv[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
        sox([argv + ["127.0.0.1", ], argv][len(argv) == 3])
```

**IRC**

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

from soxxy import *

lo_host = None
lo_port = None
remote_host = None
remote_port = None

def send(bs):
        s = socket()
        s.connect((lo_host, int(lo_port)))
        s.send(bs)
        x = s.recv(8192)
        s.close()
        return x

if __name__ == "__main__":
        lo_host, lo_port, remote_host, remote_port = argv[1:]
        send(bytes([CNCT, ] + [ord(c) for c in remote_host + ":" + remote_port]))
        from time import sleep
        sleep(8)
        print(str(send(bytes([RECV, ])), enc))
        send(bytes([DISC, ]))
```

**Test case**

```
$ cat test.sh 
./soxxy.py 8000 & sleep 2 && \
./irc 127.0.0.1 8000 irc.gnu.org 6667
$ sh test.sh 
:morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Looking up your hostname...
:morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Checking Ident
:morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** Found your hostname
:morgan.freenode.net NOTICE * :*** No Ident response
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `enc = enc()` is considered an anti-pattern, because the semantics of `enc` changes. I'd suggest renaming the variable to `encoding`.

Rather than a long `if..elif..else` block you could use a simple `handle_operation(op)` call.

Since there's effectively no exception handling it will be difficult to diagnose errors.

Using `argparse` would make it possible to understand how to use the code without reading it. As a bonus it adds `-h`/`--help` support by default so users can see what the expected call structure is.

`sleep`ing to wait for an end point to be available is an anti-pattern. To guarantee that an end point is up *and* that you get started processing as quickly as possible it's common to poll the end point until it responds correctly or fail if there's a timeout.